# Using Python to Convert Fixed Width Hierarchical File to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, fixed-width

I have a large fixed width file with lines that follow different parsing rules based on the line identifier (FH for File Header, H2 for Header 2...) Here is some sample data:

```
H20123456789 Tuesday Eastern
L1John Smith's Apple Store   1234 Wall Street    New York, New York 01234
D17777777               20191126 2507   0000000000001
D28888888           6789012             9876520000002
D17777777               20191126 3424   0000000000002
D28888888           6789012             9876520000002
HT00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
L1Mark Sloan's Flower Store  1235 23rd Street    Dallas,   Texas    01234
D17777777               20191126 1307   0000000000003
D26666666           6789012             9876520000002
HT00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
FT0382927439297843+099876333453
```

Using the line identifier (FH,H2,L1,D1,D2,HT,FT) I would like to ignore the FH, HT and FT lines, and combine all detail lines with their associated header line and convert this data into a csv. I would like the output text to follow the pattern:

```
H2,L1,D1,D2
```

For the sample data above, I would like the output to be:

```
0123456789 Tuesday Eastern,John Smith's Apple Store,1234 Wall Street,New York,New York,01234,7777777,20191126,2507,0000000000001,8888888,6789012,9876520000002
0123456789 Tuesday Eastern,John Smith's Apple Store,1234 Wall Street,New York,New York,01234,7777777,20191126,3424,0000000000002,8888888,6789012,9876520000002
0123456789 Tuesday Eastern,Mark Sloan's Flower Store,1235 23rd Street,Dallas,Texas,01239,7777777,20191126,1307,0000000000003,6666666,6789012,9876520000002
```

I have am new to Python, but I have searched stack overflow and found ways to identify lines based on their characters using this code:

```
import re  # import RegEX

lists = []  # create an array called lists
linenum = 0  # start line number count at 0
pattern = re.compile(
    r"^D1"
)  # define the RegEX patter we are looking for, ^ means line must start with
with open("readthis.txt", "rt") as myfile:  # open the text file in read mode
    for line in myfile:  # for each line in this file
        if pattern.search(line) != None:  # If the pattern is found above
            lists.append(
                (linenum, line.rstrip("\n"))
            )  # list the full line and remove any extra whitespace between lines
for sub in lists:  # Iterate over the list of tuples
    print(sub[1])  # print the lines that match
```

This finds and prints the rows I need, but it doesn't help with parsing. I also am using this code to parse out a file based on the "config.txt" file, but I can't find a way to store lines as variables and carry the L1 records through the file:

```
"""
This script will convert Fixed width File into Delimiter File, tried on Python 3.5 only
Sample run: (Order of argument doesnt matter)
python ConvertFixedToDelimiter.py -i SrcFile.txt -o TrgFile.txt -c Config.txt -d "|"
Inputs are as follows
1. Input FIle - Mandatory(Argument -i) - File which has fixed Width data in it
2. Config File - Optional (Argument -c, if not provided will look for Config.txt file on same path, if not present script will not run)
    Should have format as
    FieldName,fieldLength
    eg:
    FirstName,10
    SecondName,8
    Address,30
    etc:
3. Output File - Optional (Argument -o, if not provided will be used as InputFIleName plus _Delimited.txt)
4. Delimiter - Optional (Argument -d, if not provided default value is "," (comma))
"""
from collections import OrderedDict
import argparse
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os.path
import sys

# Define how to parse the file
def slices(s, args):
    position = 0
    for length in args:
        length = int(length)
        yield s[position:position + length]
        position += length

# Check to make sure argparse is loaded
def extant_file(x):
    """
    'Type' for argparse - checks that file exists but does not open.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(x):
        # Argparse uses the ArgumentTypeError to give a rejection message like:
        # error: argument input: x does not exist
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("{0} does not exist".format(x))
    return x

# Define arguments
parser = ArgumentParser(description="Please provide your Inputs as -i InputFile -o OutPutFile -c ConfigFile")
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="InputFile", required=True,    help="Provide your Input file name here, if file is on different path than where this script resides then provide full path of the file", metavar="FILE", type=extant_file)
parser.add_argument("-o", dest="OutputFile", required=False,    help="Provide your Output file name here, if file is on different path than where this script resides then provide full path of the file", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_argument("-c", dest="ConfigFile", required=False,   help="Provide your Config file name here,File should have value as fieldName,fieldLength. if file is on different path than where this script resides then provide full path of the file", metavar="FILE",type=extant_file)
parser.add_argument("-d", dest="Delimiter", required=False,   help="Provide the delimiter string you want",metavar="STRING", default=",")

# Use arguments defined above
args = parser.parse_args()

#Input file madatory
InputFile = args.InputFile
#Delimiter by default ","
DELIMITER = args.Delimiter

#Check to see if an Output file name has been specified, if not default to filename + _Delimited
if args.OutputFile is None:
    OutputFile = str(InputFile) + "_Delimited.txt"
    print ("Setting Ouput file as "+ OutputFile)
else:
    OutputFile = args.OutputFile

# Check to make sure the Config file exists in the same directory as the python script
if args.ConfigFile is None:
    if not os.path.exists("Config.txt"):
        print ("There is no Config File provided exiting the script")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        ConfigFile = "Config.txt"
        print ("Taking Config.txt file on this path as Default Config File")
else:
    ConfigFile = args.ConfigFile

# Create an array for field names, field length
fieldNames = []
fieldLength = []
myvars = OrderedDict()

# Read the configuration file and define the variables in the file in the arrays created above
with open(ConfigFile) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        name, var = line.partition(",")[::2]
        myvars[name.strip()] = int(var)
for key,value in myvars.items():
    fieldNames.append(key)
    fieldLength.append(value)

# Create the output file
# Use the field length to slice the input file and join the sliced pieces with commas in new lines in the output file
with open(OutputFile, 'w') as f1:
    fieldNames = DELIMITER.join(map(str, fieldNames))
    f1.write(fieldNames + "\n")
    with open(InputFile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            rec = (list(slices(line, fieldLength)))
            myLine = DELIMITER.join(map(str, rec))
            f1.write(myLine + "\n")
```

Comment: If the fields are fixed-width, and you know which "type" each line is, what is the problem you're having with parsing?

Comment: I do not know how to store the H1 and L1 lines as temporary variables to combine with their respective D1 and D2 lines. I think if I could concatenate the detail lines with their headers, then I could use one global parsing rule for those combined lines.

I was originally thinking about parsing each line based on their own definition and then combing them, but it seems like it would be easier to combine first and then parse second.